# VSCode integrated terminal(fish)’s pwd command always returns “/“

Tags: visual-studio-code, fish

I'm using VSCode Integrated terminal with `/usr/local/bin/fish`.

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/usr/local/bin/fish",
```

In VSCode's integrated terminal, `pwd` command always returns "/" regardless of a directory I opened with.

```sh
pwd
# => /
echo $PWD
# => /
```

How can I change the pwd with a path of the directory I opened?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in fish 3.0.1: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5647.

The solution is to upgrade to fish 3.0.2.